# How to create custom error page in sharepoint 2013

Tags: error, custom, aspx

I want to create the custom error page for site.

Comment: if you want to do it without VS, here is a good [link](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/01/22/sharepoint-2013-custom-error-pages-aspx/) explaining how to do it.

Comment: Xavi's link should answer your question. Also here is PowerShell to set your page not found URL:
$spsite = Get-SPSite "Web site URL"
$spsite.filenotfoundurl
$spsite.filenotfoundurl = "/sites/yoursite/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can choose any of the 3 options from below.

**Option 1**: Replace the default `PageNotFoundError.aspx` in the Page Library – One of the easiest and Convenient way to replace default text in `PageNotFoundError.aspx` is to either edit the `PageNotFoundError.aspx` that resides in the Page Library or to delete it and replace it with a Custom error Page that has the same i.e. PageNotFoundError page name.

If you choose to do this –

a) You would loose the default Created Page

b) You cannot replace the `PageNotFoundError.aspx` with a Custom Error Page that you have deployed in 15 hive.

**Option 2**: Using `SPSite.FileNotFoundUrl property` – You can use the Out-of-Box `SPSite.FileNotFoundUrl` property of a Site to Change the URL of default Page Not Found page that is used for the entire site.

You can use the following PowerShell Commands to do this –

```
$spsite = Get-SPSite "Web App URL"
$spsite.FileNotFoundUrl = "URL of the Custom Error Page"
```

**Option 3**: Using SharePoint Designer 2013 (set `vti_filenotfoundpage` property) – With the new Site Options in `SharePoint Designer 2013`, you can assign the `vti_filenotfoundpage` property of the site to a Custom Error Page that you might have deployed in the 15 Hive.

Open your Site in Designer -> Under Manage section -> click on `Site Options` -> In Parameters(tab) modify `vti_filenotfoundpage` property to add a relative URL to your Custom error Page deployed in 15 Hive.

Refer below screen shot –

[image]

Refer [Replace default PageNotFoundError.aspx with Custom Error Page in SharePoint 2013](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/06/17/replace-default-pagenotfounderror-aspx-with-custom-error-page-in-sharepoint-2013/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Xavi's link should answer your question. Also here is PowerShell to set your page not found URL:

```
$spsite = Get-SPSite "Web site URL"
$spsite.filenotfoundurl
$spsite.filenotfoundurl = "/sites/yoursite/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx"
```